# Converting special German characters (umlauts) to regular UTF-8 chars

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, utf-8

I have a string which basically looks like this when I get it back through the API response:

```
Ardap Fogger � Zuverl�ssiger Vernebler Zur Ungeziefer- Und Flohbek�mpfung F
```

The final version of the string should look like this once I convert it in C#:

```
Ardap Fogger – Zuverlässiger Vernebler Zur Ungeziefer- Und Flohbekämpfung F
```

I have tried several methods o conversions like following:

```
public string ConvertStringToUTF8(string title)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(title);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

This didn't work. I have also tried following method:

```
var title = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(" Ardap Fogger � Zuverl�ssiger Vernebler Zur Ungeziefer- Und Flohbek�mpfung F");
```

Both methods result in same string as the one entered.

How can I convert this string to this version:

```
Ardap Fogger – Zuverlässiger Vernebler Zur Ungeziefer- Und Flohbekämpfung F
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Comment: You need to change the encoding at the source. Either your API server is writing it in the wrong encoding or you read it in the wrong encoding. If the encoding is wrong you can't correct it afterwards. Also, don't use `Encoding.Default` as this will only cause issues due to it being different on different machines.

Comment: How is your content being sent from the browser to the server? Do you specify the content-encoding in a header? The server receives the request boy as an arry of bytes, and try to convert them to a string using the wrong enconding. The encoding must match. You cannot "reconvert" the string, becasie the original info has already been lost

Answer (score 1):

First you should know in what encoding is your source. Most probably it is German MS-DOS. 
try encoding page 850 : Encoding.GetEncoding(850). Also your c# code already has an encoding, probably UTF. So you try to convert UTF to UTF. Try reading from a file.

```
public string ConvertStringToUTF8(string title)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(title);
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetString(data);
}
```

Comment: Will this work for all special characthers, even for non German ones, Swedish, French etc etc ?

Comment: @User987 Probably not, you'll need to know the encoding of each file and ensure you specify the correct encoding for each.

Comment: That code page was created for western European languages with diacritics. Should work for most of them